# Apache - Move /wordpress installation to main website address

Tags: https, wordpress

I just re-installed wordpress in Debian server and it sits in /var/www/html/wordpress directory. I used wordpress in the past, so I have partially configured things, just need to polish it a bit.
I would like to have wordpress on the main address mywebsite.com. So I need to redirect entire wordpress from /var/www/html/wordpress to main apache root directory.
I am a bit overwhelmed with all options available.
I have so far determined that I could/should edit configuration of:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

This file contains currently (among other lines):

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I don't know if this is correct or not. Furthermore:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf
```

This one says:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
```

And lastly, I use 443 https only, very nicely secured with Let's Encrypt, defined in:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

I use proxy redirection there, so my unrelated service is available online via https under mywebsite.com/service. That I want to stay as it is, unrelated to wordpress, is works very well currently. This is the entire file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mywebsite.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/var/run/apache2/stapling_cache(128000)
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        
        ProxyPass               /service http://127.0.0.1:port/service
        ProxyPassReverse        /service http://127.0.0.1:port/service

        ServerName mywebsite.com
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
        SSLUseStapling on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Can someone tell me please where should make this entry so wordpress installed in /var/www/html/wordpress is displayed as my main website address, https://mywebsite.com? And I still have my other service available under mywebsite.com/service?
I tried some configuration changes and it worked, but I realized that
https://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php does not redirect properly and I can't login to wordpress.
Thank you!

Comment: You will need to change `DocumentRoot` to point to `/var/www/html/wordpress`. But you will most likely have to change something in the Wordpress config aswell - I don't know WP but it will be "base_url" or something similar (you'll probably need to remove the extra `/wordpress`

Comment: Thank you, DocumentRoot in
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf
or
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Or should I create another one, wordpress.conf and configure it there?